# Integrate OpenID Connect Authentication on Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, openid

I have a site, and I am trying to integrate the OpenID Connect.

Locally, when user visit : `http://127.0.0.1/user/login`

I redirect them to open id log-in page - if their session is not authenticated :

```
https://login.uat.site.be/openid/oauth/authorize?client_id=site&state=28633813-cd2a-47aa-bb6f-62f623013a6c&nonce=3d42b1c5-cc85-4264-a66c-e9e768ac0d1c&response_type=code&claims=%7B%22id_token%22%3A%7B%22http%3A%2F%2Fsite.be%2Fclaims%2Froles%22%3Anull%7D%7D
```

Then, user will prompt to enter their username and password, if success, they will redirect back to registered URL :

```
https://www.livesite.com/dashboard?code=fnJk7xhja0TiF2qKevqC7U94zuk6exwa&state=28633813-cd2a-47aa-bb6f-62f623013a6c
```

**Note** : I must registered : https://www.livesite.com/dashboard with my OpenID Auth Server.

Now, I want to access my `code` param locally, how do I do that  ?

> **Note** : code=fnJk7xhja0TiF2qKevqC7U94zuk6exwa

I understand that I register `https://www.livesite.com/dashboard` with my Auth Server, but, I need to finish my local development first before moving this to production.

---

## Questions

Should I request the OpenID Auth Server to register my local route ?

Will I have to make my local development HTTPS for this to work ?

Comment: Any OAuth client must be registered on OAuth provider with app's key, secret, and callback url to allow auth flow. Are facing any particular problem, or just general lack of experience working with OpenID Connect?